# What does the 'access_civicrm_nav_link' permission allow?

Tags: permissions

I'm currently reviewing the permissions for a CiviCRM/WordPress site. Some of the user roles have the 'access_civicrm_nav_link' permission but I'm not sure what this is used for.  I couldn't find any documentation for it except for a reference to it in one of the WordPress integration files:

[/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php#L185)

Am I right in thinking that this permission dates back to an earlier version of CiviCRM and is no longer used?

Is it safe to remove this permission from the user roles?

CiviCRM 4.6 / WordPress 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a search at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress there's a note about it being changed and the lack of search results indicate it's no longer used.

EDIT: At github you can go back as far as v4.4 and see that it's not used, and while the old svn repo is no longer available you can see from https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12731 that it was used at that point and possibly even removed as part of that issue, somewhere around 4.2.

Comment: I could only find a reference in the file I mentioned in my question. I presume that means it is no longer in use.

Comment: I've updated my answer.